# OneSignal - How to get players ID

Tags: php, angularjs

[image]

I want to use push notification in my ionic version 1 project. I have subscribed device in OneSignal. I want to get player id when a user gets logged in.
Please help me.

Comment: _Please help me._ How are we supposed to help you if you don't show any code etc.. SO is not a free coding service

Comment: Show your efforts. This is not a write for me community...

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `push` method with `getUserId` as parameter

```
OneSignal.push(["getUserId", function(playerId) {
//console.log("OneSignal User ID:", playerId);
if(playerId){
     var url    = SITEURL;
                    $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    type:'post',
                    async:true,
                    data:{ playerId : playerId, isAjax : 'Yes' },
                    success:function(data){
                    //console.log("OneSignal User ID:", playerId);                      
                    }
});
}
```

}]);